# linking mit inventor2 to sql database error 1109

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to connect my hosted sql database with mitinventor2 in a registeration form and I am getting an error that says something about

> URL.  error 1109

This is my php code :

```
    <?php 

    DEFINE ('DBUSER', '******'); 
    DEFINE ('DBPW', '*****'); 
    DEFINE ('DBHOST', 's******'); 
    DEFINE ('DBNAME', '*******'); 

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
    if (!$dbc) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
        exit();
    }

    $dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
    if (!$dbs) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
        exit(); 
    }


$clientusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['clientusername']);
$clientemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['clientemail']);
$clientpno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['clientpno']);
$clientpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['clientpass']);


$query = "INSERT INTO ssudb(clientusername, clientemail,  clientpno, clientpass) VALUES ('$clientusername', '$clientemail', '$clientpno', '$clientpass')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc)); 

    mysqli_close($dbc); 

    ?>
```

I am sure about the database info yet I hide them for security reasons. My database is well structured with phpmyadmin.

The link to the php file is right with no errors, and here is my mit inventor block:

I hope I didn't validate any rule. 
Thanks in advance!

note: 
when  open phpmyadmin somtimes i see the table is having new attributes with no values in it but the increment ID.

[image: blocks]

Answer (score 0):

$clientlocation is missing in the VALUES

Comment: i fixed that thank you... but the sql database is still not added